# Create a new Object from an Array of ObjectsLoop

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to loop through an Array and create/add to another object.

```js
let list = [
    {id:1, parent_id: 1, location: "place1", content: "hello"}, 
    {id:2, parent_id: 2, location: "place2", content: "hello again"},
    {id:3, parent_id: 1, location: "place1", content: "hello"}
]

let newObjList = {
    place1: {},
    place2: {}
}

list.forEach(i => {
    let noteId = i.id
    let parentId = i.parent_id
    let location = i.location === "place1" 
                   ? "place1" :
                      i.location === "place2" 
                      ? "place2" : null;

    let existingKeyList = !!location ? Object.keys(newObjList[location]) : []

    let existingKeySet = new Set(existingKeyList)

    let listHasKey = existingKeySet.has(parentId)

    if(!listHasKey) {
        newObjList[itemType][parentId] = {}
        newObjList[itemType][parentId][noteId] = i
    } else {
        newObjList[itemType][parentId][noteId] = i
    }
})
```

In the end, I want the new Object to look like this:

```js
{
    place1: {
        1: {id:1, parent_id: 1, location: "place1", content: "hello"}, 
        3: {id:3, parent_id: 1, location: "place1", content: "hello"}
    },
    place2: {
        2: {id:2, parent_id: 2, location: "place2", content: "hello again"}
    }
}
```

My attempt to achieve this with `forEach()` is just returning the last item from the array in my newObjList. Like this:

```
newObjList: {
    place1: { 
        3: { id:3, parent_id: 1, location: "place1", content: "hello" }
    },
    place2: {}
}
```

Any ideas on how to achieve the desired result?

Comment: The basic description of your goal is what the `.reduce()` method was intended for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `reduce`-function to achive that.

Here are some resources:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

And

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp

Below is an example using your use case.

```js
let list = [{id:1, parent_id: 1, location: "place1", content: "hello"}, {id:2, parent_id: 2, location: "place2", content: "hello again"}, {id:3, parent_id: 1, location: "place1", content: "hello"}]
    
const myObject = list.reduce((prev, item) => {
  prev[item.location][item.id] = item;
  return prev;
}, {place1: {}, place2: {}});

console.log(myObject)
```

Comment: Thank you! This works great and I appreciate the resources.

Comment: Glad this worked for you :) If you are satisfied with the solution and it works as intended, then please mark it as the correct answer so that others can benefit from it as well.